# What happens the transistors in a chip as the temperature increases?

Tags: transistors

If the chip stop operating properly, then as it gets hotter the transistors fail, eventually to the point where the silicon in the transistor melts.

I'm after the whole process of how a temperature increase affects the chip, until the chip is destroyed.

Comment: I can virtually guarantee that by the time the silicon gets even close to melting, the chip has long, long be destroyed. Melting is not the point! Brownian motion is, though, so these phenomena aren't unrelated.

Comment: There are many failure mechanisms that are accelerated by temperature. You are essentially asking for a complete discussion of how semiconductors fail, which is far to broad for this site. If you think the silicon melts then you need to do a great deal of learning before you can reasonably address this topic.

Comment: As you increase die temperature eventually the doped silicon becomes intrinsic from thermal carrier generation and your chip won't function correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transistors don't just "fail" at some given temperature.  For silicon devices, as temperature increases, the devices get slower and their leakage increases.  At some point their performance drops off to the point that the device that they are part of, be it a gate, flip flop, ASIC, FPGA, or a microprocessor doesn't meet it's spec'd performance.  For industrial grade parts, this is usually 70 deg C.  For mil-aero parts, it's 125 deg C.

Also, other parts of the system will fail long before the silicon starts to melt.  Silicon has a melting point of approximately 1400 deg C.  The solder that attaches the part to the board has a melting point of around 185 deg C, depending on the type of solder.